# parsing this format of date dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss with logstack

Tags: filter, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

my timestamp in the logs have this format below:

```
<p> 2018/03/15  16:22:31    SYST                    DEBUG :: RefOPoolConnexionsSQL::getConnexionSQL() --> A016  </P>
```

I need to have something like that`{
  "
  "_type": "logs",
  "_method1": "SYST",
  "_method2": "DEBUG",
  "line": RefOPoolConnexionsSQL::getConnexionSQL() --> A016,
  "_source": {
    "path": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "@timestamp": "2018/03/15  16:22:31, **logstash @timestamp**
    "timestamp": "2018/03/15  16:22:31"   **Mine time stamp**
  }`

for that i do this filter but it didnt work as i want:

```js
input {
   beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{WORD:client} %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:sys} %{GREEDYDATA:line}" }
  }
  date {
        match => ["timestamp", "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss"]
        target => "@timestamp"
     }
}


output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: what output are you getting?

Comment: i got a timestamp by default that have this format 20018-03-20T13:00:00Z

Comment: Have a look at this to modify your output timestamp format - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html